# axios js predefined response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I found and trying to use this code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Update from './Update'

const Profile = ({user, setUser})=>{
    const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    axios.get('/logout')
    .then(res=>{        
        localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken')
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
        setUser({ auth:false, name:'' })
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
    return(
        <div>
        <p>{`Hi ${user.name}`}</p>
        <Update/>
        <button type='submit' onClick= {e=> handleLogout(e)}>Logout</button></div>
    )
}
export default Profile
```

but there's no 'logout' endpoint at the BE, so my intention is to 'hack' this module to make it auto-response *'ok'* (or whatever) by istelf, and reach the *remove token* and *user* lines.
Needless to say this is just educational, no mean to do it 'the right way', but just to avoid touching the BE.

I've tryied this code out (by chatgpt) but seems not working:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Update from './Update';

const Profile = ({ user, setUser }) => {
  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e);

    // Intercept the axios GET request and return a custom response
    axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      if (config.url === '/logout' && config.method === 'get') {
        console.log('within-interceptor');
        return Promise.resolve({
          data: 'Logout successful', // This is your custom response message
          status: 200, // HTTP status code for success
          statusText: 'OK', // HTTP status text for success
          headers: {}, // Response headers
          config: config, // The original request config
        });
      }
      return config;
    });

    axios
      .get('/logout')
      .then((res) => {
        
        localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
        setUser({ auth: false, name: '' });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => {
        // Remove the interceptor to avoid affecting other requests
        axios.interceptors.request.eject(0);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`Hi ${user.name}`}</p>
      <Update />
      <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => handleLogout(e)}>
        Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

..after pressing the 'logout' button -despite that console.log is being printed, I continue seeing the token at the local storage of the devtool's application tab.

The esasiest walkaroud will be the best solution to my problem. (I'll have time later to learn it the right way).

Very thanks in advance.

Comment: If there's no API endpoint to access and you just want to perform the resulting actions, why make an AJAX operation at all?  Why not just perform the resulting actions that you want to perform?  It's not really clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The easiest way would definitely be to *not* try and call a non-existent endpoint, then try to mock  a successful response from it only to call some code that should execute after the call. The easiest solution is to call the code without jumping through all the hoops.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ , your words helped me on how to face and fix the problem  - sometimes we need just an hint pointing to the logical approach rather than the written solution (completely newbie to this async world).  Take a look at my response to David if wanna figure out what was going on. Thanks again!

Comment: hi @David , thanks 4 taking your time answering. I've already worked it out thanks to VLAZ suggestion. Gonna try to explain what I'm in:
I'm trying to learn by myself back-end coding; I got acces to a working one (develop) which uses a working db and 'tokens api' as well, but I'm not autorized to modify any data on such servers. I've already done using postman to test BE endpoints but wanted a FrontEnd just to play around, so I used a react/axios code I found in the internet which performs logins and logouts, but there's no logout endpoint at the BE, that's why wanted any way to mimic it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easier than what I thought: just removing the `axios.get` call.
Thanks to all out there!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).